# Why is this modular arithmetic incorrect in my rotate string function?

Tags: c, string, math, modulus

I am writing a rotate string function in C. The intended behavior is that the strings chars will be rotated using a modulus of the string length, and a key. The function seems to work in the forward direction, but if I specify a negative key, I want the string to rotate in the opposite direction, and this is where the bug exists. For completeness/testing purposes, I will supply the entire program, but below that I will highlight the problem area and explain what I've done to try to debug so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *rotate_str(char *mutable_str, int key);

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "This is a test.";

    char *output = rotate_str(str, -2);
    printf("%s\n", output);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//Bug - negative rotate doesn't work properly - test with -2
char *rotate_str(char *mutable_str, int key) {
    assert(mutable_str);
    size_t len = strlen(mutable_str);
    ssize_t i;
    char *output = malloc(len + 1);
    assert(output);

    ssize_t rotated_index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        rotated_index = (i + key) % len; // Get the new index position
        output[rotated_index] = mutable_str[i];
    }
    output[len] = '\0';
    return output;
}
```

The trouble spot is:

```
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        rotated_index = (i + key) % len; // Get the new index position
        output[rotated_index] = mutable_str[i];
    }
```

On the first iteration, `i = 0`, `key = -2`, and `len = 15`. When I compute `-2 + 0 % 15` using a calculator (Google in this case), I get `13`. However, my C program is making `rotated_index = 14` as per my debugger output. So this itself is already a concern.

When I do a positive `2` as `key`, I get output: `t.This is a tes`, which is what I'd expect. But when I do the `-2` as `key`, I get output: `is is a test.` but the expected output is `is is a test.Th`

Comment: _When I compute -2 + 0 % 15 using a calculator (Google in this case), I get 13_,  though `-2 + 0 % 15` --> `-2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modulo operation with negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers)

Comment: @DavidRanieri In C, `-2 + 0 % 15` is just `-2 + 0` since `%` binds more tightly than `+`.

Comment: The `%` in C is a remainder; its behaviour is described in the link r3mainer gave above. You can fix your code by making the the numerator positive: Add `len` to the `key` before the loop or calculate `(i + key + len) % len`

Comment: @TomKarzes And that's what I said ;) `-2 + 0 % 15` --> `-2`

Comment: The `%` operator in C is a remainder operator.  It does not perform a mod function the way it's normally defined in mathematics (unless the first operand is non-negative and the second is positive).  You can add multiples of `len` to `i + key` before appying `%`, forcing it into the non-negative range, or you can check its sign and handle the negative case specially.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has to do with using the modulo operator with negative numbers.

1. To start with, you are using size_t which is an unsigned type, but you are trying to put negative numbers into the unsigned type. There is a better explanation why this is an issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39337256/13341069
2. Handle the key < (len * -1).

   ```
    char* rotate_str(char *mutable_str, int key)
    {
        assert(mutable_str);
        int len = strlen(mutable_str);
        int i;
        char *output = (char *)malloc(len + 1);
        assert(output);

        int remainder;
        int rotated_index = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            remainder = (i + key) % len; // Get the new index position. range is (-len to +len)
            rotated_index = (remainder + len) % len; // Add len to shift value range to [0, +len).
            output[rotated_index] = mutable_str[i];
        }
        output[len] = '\0';
        return output;
    }
   ```